# sum of decimals in excel vba

Tags: excel, integer, decimal, vba

I want to sum the cells of one column using excel vba. The values in the cells are deimals, however, the sum given by excel vba is always an integer. For example: 2.5 +2.1 = 4.6 excel will display 5. How can I show the 4.6 value?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **Double** data type:

```
Sub SumTheValues()
    Dim zum As Double
    zum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A:A"))
    MsgBox zum
End Sub
```

For your data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found from another post. Option 4 to be the best - https://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-cells-based-on-background-color

I then took what was above and replace one word - "as long" to "as double" and now the function works perfectly with colors.

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Dim cSum As Double
Dim ColIndex As Integer
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
  If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.sum(cl, cSum)
  End If
Next cl
SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```